# How to prove that for any permutation and ordered set it will eventualy returns to itself?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We start with the ordered $[n]$ and apply a permutation $f$ multiple times it will eventually go back to the ordered set $[n]$

For example:

Let's start with the ordered set $[9]$, and apply $f(x)$ $6$ times.
$$f(x) = \begin{pmatrix} {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}\\
{7} & {5} & {1} & {9} & {8} & {4} & {2} & {3} & {6} \end{pmatrix}$$
We will get:

$1: \{7, 5, 1, 9, 8, 4, 2, 3, 6\}$

$2: \{2, 8, 7, 6, 3, 9, 5, 1, 4\}$

$3: \{5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9\}$

$4: \{8, 1, 5, 9, 7, 4, 3, 2, 6\}$

$5: \{3, 7, 8, 6, 2, 9, 1, 5, 4\}$

$6: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$

How can I prove that for any finite set and $f(x)$ this holds true

Comment: Start with (a) any such $f$ is a bijection and (b) there are at most $n!$ possible orderings

Comment: $f^{n!} = \text{id}$.

Comment: A permutation can be thought of as a graph. Construct directed edge $u, v$ iff $p[v] = u$. The permutation is just various disjoint simple cycles, and it will go back to original in $LCM$ of the sizes of the components.

Comment: Useful PDF: http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math4361/permutations

Answer (score 1):

This happens in all finite groups. Notice that each permutation has an inverse, so they form a group. Now, since the group is finite, some element must be repeated, i.e. for a permutation $\sigma$ there are some natural numbers $s<t$ s.t.

$$\sigma^s = \sigma^t.$$

From this we can cancel $\sigma^s$ to get $\sigma^{t-s} = id$.